# CSS not included on server-side rendered page in NextJS application

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

In my NextJS project, I've imported my css file in the top of _app.tsx like so:

```js
import '../main.css'
```

I'm using Tailwind CSS with the correct content paths in the tailwind.config.js file, and the main.css file has the usual Tailwind required tags.

In development, every page works completely fine, but in production the CSS does not work on the index page. The index page is the only page in the project that is server-side rendered.

I noticed that the static css bundle is not included in the index HTML document at all, so I have no clue why NextJS is not including it on the server-side rendered pages.

Anyone know if this is fixable somehow or just a bug?

(NextJS 13.1.5)

Answer (score 0):

try importing a global css module like this `import '@/styles/globals.css'`

then you need to add tailwind css the top of the global.css file like this

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```